# Go to type of var in VIsual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

If I press `F12` on a `var` variable in Visual Studio, it will navigate to where that variable is initialized.  However, how do I navigate to the inferred type of that variable?

Comment: What? Surely they are the same thing. You mean how do you for example navigate to the class definition for the type?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have the `var` keyword selected (either fully or caret on it) and then press `F12`, it will take you to the class.

I just tested this on a string `var` and it took me to the `String` class.

I do not believe there is a way to jump straight from the variable name to the class, you have to do it as a 2-step process:

1. variable > declaration (var)
2. var > class.